# Android Studio 1.5.1 - Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size

Tags: android, android-studio

How to resolve the following issue in Android Studio 1.5.1 Version:
I tried to increase and decrease the option in dx.bat file like:

```
set defaultXmx=-Xmx512M 
set defaultXmx=-Xmx1024M 
set defaultXmx=-Xmx2048M
```

**still no success.** Please let me know other option to solve this.

```
    Error:Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error:A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexQaDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat -JXmx4g --dex --no-optimize --multi-dex --main-dex-list
```

Comment: Did you set a java_opts variable somewhere ?

Comment: No, I haven't set anything like "java_opts".

Comment: I changed javaMaxHeapSize "4g" to javaMaxHeapSize "1g" in dexOptions in build.gradle file and it's working fine now.
 dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "1g"
        //jumboMode true
    }

Comment: I suggest you turn this into an answer

Comment: What are you dependencies? I would advise against this.

Answer (score 0):

I changed javaMaxHeapSize "4g" to javaMaxHeapSize "1g" in dexOptions in build.gradle file and it's working fine now. dexOptions { incremental true javaMaxHeapSize "1g" //jumboMode true }